# Babel extensions

Tags: babeljs, babel-node, babel-cli

How do I specify different extensions for babel to revolve, like webpack's [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions)? I want to use .web.js in my browser build and (something like) .server.js for my node server files, so that this:

`import foo from './foo';`

Will import the right file. I know about babel-cli/babel-node `---extensions` and that has babel determine if it will transpile a file after it's already been resolved. I want an option (ideally in . babelrc or cli args) for resolving.